# Change margins on single product page woocommerce

Tags: css, woocommerce

I have been customizing the single product page a little, all is fine.
However, there are big spaces between the titles, prices, variation colors, buttons, etc. It's even worse on mobile, you nearly need to scroll an entire page before you can add the product to cart.
I need to have less space, thus adjust the margins, between the price and the color variations, and between the color variations and the add to cart button.

I inspected the elements on my page with the chrome tools for developers. 
I selected some things and i can SEE there's room with nothing in it. See the orange box on the picture. I tried the codes shown below to adjust the margins, they sadly do not work.

```
.form.variations_form.cart {
margin-top: -5% !important;
}

.woocommerce-variation single_variation {
margin-bottom: -9px;
}
```

I think I might have the wrong class or ID even though I checked it with inspector tools on chrome. Truth is I am no magic coder and I will never solve this unless I get a lead. If anyone has any tips or adjustments to my code, I would be very happy to try it.

Comment: Do you have the page live somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

A few things, you have margin on these elements:

```
//margin top of the cart section
.woocommerce div.product form.cart, .woocommerce div.product p.cart {
  margin-top: 2.45em;
}

//margin bottom under variations table
.woocommerce div.product form.cart .variations {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

//hidden description section, causes a tiny gap above quantity box
.single_variation {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

And you have padding-top inline on this element:

```
<div id="wc-stripe-payment-request-wrapper" style="clear:both;padding-top:1.5em;">
  <div id="wc-stripe-payment-request-button" style="display: none;">
    <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Remove the margins and padding and you have

[image]

Update:

If the div is from a plugin, you can try overriding it by doing:

```
#wc-stripe-payment-request-wrapper {
  padding-top: 0!important;
}
```

and for the description part, you have a few margins too:

```
.woocommerce div.product div.summary {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.woocommerce div.product form.cart {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

and when on mobile, you have this margin bottom:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .woocommerce #content div.product div.images, .woocommerce #content div.product div.summary, .woocommerce div.product div.images, .woocommerce div.product div.summary {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
}
```

and you have this class with no content but takes a bit of space too, not that important, but maybe try removing it if you don't need it:

```
.product-share-wrap {
}
```

Comment: I am forever thankful- it looks a lot better now. Only the second bit (<div> Stripe code) I cannot manage to find (it's a plugin). One last thing: under the photos under add to cart button, there's a huge space on the mobile screen until you reach the description tab. It's fine on laptop, just not on phone.

Comment: So a code I could add would be like; @media (max-width: 768px) {.XXXX {margin-top:0}}  but again I fail in finding the correct class/ID name (.XXXX). You'd be a savior if it's not too much work for you to find the correct class/id. Also sorry for the split comments on this page, I was too late to edit them. Thank you for your help and time once again